# how to check ram consumption javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

I need to improve the performance of a script done in Javascript, and I can check the RAM consumption script said.

for example like the PHP function `get_memory_get_peak()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Chrome, if you run with the `--enable-memory-info` flag, you can get the data from:

```
console.memory;
```

which contains:

```
jsHeapSizeLimit
totalJSHeapSize
usedJSHeapSize
```

This data can also be fetched from a memory heap snapshot by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>, but this is not programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot read memory data using JavaScript code. A method to see the memory consumption is by inspecting the process.

Chrome has a built-in statistics screen, which can be summoned using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>. This screen shows various information about each tab, including memory consumption.

Answer (score 3):

The Chrome developer tools include a heap profiler: http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/heap-profiling.html

Answer (score -8):

You could format the PHP code with CSS & JS, but that's about it. Use the PHP Function, and HTML can't do that, it's just a ***markup*** language.

```
    <?php
    print(get_memory_get_peak());
    ?>
```

Try using the **Task *Manager***, go to processes, and check the usage stats!

Comment: I don't think that will say anything about JavaScript's usage; he's trying to improve a JavaScript script.

Comment: Then try going to Task Manager in Windows.... Check the Process CPU and RAM Stats...